# Firebase .indexOn warning

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

This is my data structure with query string.

Data structure

```js
{
 "root_firebase_DB": {
  "users": [{
   "meUID": {
    "name": "ME",
    "rooms": [{
     "room_id_01": true
    }]
   }
  }, {
   "friendUID": {
    "name": "FRIEND",
    "rooms": [{
     "room_id_01": true
    }]
   }
  }],
  "rooms": [{
   "room_id_01": {
    "meUID": true,
    "friendUID": true
   }
  }],
  "messages": [{
   "room_id_01": {
    "message_id_01": {
     "text": "Hello world",
     "user": {
      "_id": "meUID",
      "name": "ME"
     }
    },
    "message_id_02": {
     "text": "Xin Chao",
     "user": {
      "_id": "friendUID",
      "name": "FRIEND"
     }
    }
   }
  }]
 }
}
```

I have `meUID` and `friendUID`, i want to find a room that contain both us.

The query bellow is fine, but i got `.indexOn` warning
[image: warning]

```js
const meUID = 'abc';
const friendUID = 'abc';
/**
* Find room key
* filter by meUID and friendUID
*
* THIS WAY I GOT WARNING .indexON
*
*/
firebase.database().ref()
    .child('rooms')
    .orderByChild(meUID)
    .equalTo(true)
    .on('child_added', snap => {
      if (snap.hasChild(friendUID)) {
        console.log('Got roomKEY', snap.key);
      }
    });
```

In general way, i get array of rooms by `meUID` and loop, each loop i go to filter as bellow to find Is this room have my `friendUID` or not, this way i have no warning with index, but seem waste time to loop and check all rooms.

```js
/**
* THIS WAY NOT GET ANY WARNING
* BUT IS THERE OTHER GOOD WAY TO GO?
*/
const ref = firebase.database().ref();
const meUID = 'aaa';
const friendUID = 'bbb';
const messages = [];

ref.child(`users/${meUID}/rooms`).once('value', snap => {
  const roomKey = null;
  // loop all room that belong to me
  snap.forEach(room => {
    // with each room, i must going to check is this room belong to friendUID or not
    ref.child(`users/${friendUID}/rooms/${room.key}`).once('value', friendRoomSnap => {
      if (friendRoomSnap.val()) {
        // found room that belong to friendUID too
        roomKey = room.key;
      }
    });
    if (roomKey != null) {
      //if found that room, break the loop
      return true;
    }
  });
  // goto fetching all messages in this room
  ref.child(`messages/${roomKey}`).on('child_added', messageSnap => {
    messages.push(messageSnap.val());
  });
});

//Too much stuff, is there any way better?
```

Please help, i am newbie.

Does my data structure get problem?

Comment: Please replace the screenshots of text with the actual text. In the case of the JSON of your database, you can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen
I just update my question, please help.

Comment: I'm not really sure where you are stuck. To add an index, read the [Firebase documentation on adding an index](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/indexing-data) or [some other questions from people asking about indexes](https://www.google.com/search?q=site:stackoverflow.com+firebase+add+index).